# How to run net use with multiple lines of input( at once)?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

my batch currently asking for an input for one line of  net use command, and then it pauses and asks for another line of input.

My goal would be, that if i copy+paste 10 or 20 lines of directory names separated with an Enter, then it does each line and then i would have 10 or 20 attached network drive.

I couldn't find anything which can help me or i am not sure what to look for exactly.

Is it even possible?

```
@echo off
cls
:start
set /p Input=Enter shared directory name: 
net use * \\%Input%\directory /USER:someuser Somepassword
pause
goto start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the pause:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
set /p Input=Enter shared directory name: 
net use * \\%Input%\directory /USER:someuser Somepassword
goto start
```